# a simple mysql example of importing a file + can't get to work

Tags: mysql

I am having trouuble importing a file into a mysql db as it appears in the file. So I thought I'd ask a question here with a very basic example. Can anyone help me to get this to work?

I have the following file:

```
$cat NIS.txt
00000,1284
00001,2081
```

Now I go into mysql with `mysql - username -p` and I create a table(note this has to be created before you can add the rows with the LOAD DATA INFILE command)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nisC (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key',
  field1 int NOT NULL COMMENT 'field1',
  field2 int NOT NULL COMMENT 'field2',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='datatable demo table' AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;
```

Then I can add the rows with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` 
(note LOCAL is important as the file resides in the LOCAL directory?) 
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'NIS.txt' INTO TABLE nisC (field1, field2);`

this however gives me warnings

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'NIS.txt' INTO TABLE nisC (field1, field2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 4
```

And the table does not look right when I do a select:

```
mysql> select * from nisC;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      0 |      0 |
|  2 |      1 |      0 |
+----+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Why are the values in the table not the same as they are in the file?

### EDIT1 - Complete Solution/Output

**NOTE:** I have to login to mysql like this `mysql -u username -p --local-infile=1` for the `LOAD DATA` command to work.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nisC (
    ->   id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key',
    ->   field1 int NOT NULL COMMENT 'field1',
    ->   field2 int NOT NULL COMMENT 'field2',
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='datatable demo table' AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql>
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'NIS.txt' INTO TABLE nisC
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> (field1, field2)
    -> SET id = NULL;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> select * from nisC;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 |
+----+--------+--------+
| 64 |      0 |   1284 |
| 65 |      1 |   2081 |
+----+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delimeter in `LOAD DATA` so that MySQL knows it is reading CSV:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'NIS.txt' INTO TABLE nisC
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1, field2)
SET id = NULL;
```

By specifying `field1` and `field2` in the `LOAD DATA` command, MySQL will populate these two columns using the two columns of data in your CSV.  However, your table actually has a third `id` column.  In order to populate this you can instruct `LOAD DATA` to set it to `NULL`.  This will coax MySQL into assigning an auto incremented value.
You should change your column definition for `id` to make it nullable.  Then MySQL will automatically assign this id when you read in the file.

```
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key',
```

Comment: I need `LOCAL` for the `LOAD DATA` to work. Also it only adds 1 row to the table. not sure why? also what is the `\r` do here?

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: linux server on a windows PC.

Comment: If the file resides on a Linux machine, then adding `LINES TERMINATED` should resolve the issue.